# Как перенести структуру таблиц с одной базы в другую?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Пример:
У меня на локальном сервере есть база и на хостинге. Я работаю только на локальном и за тем заливаю на хост Допустим я сделал изменения в таблицах (добавил новые столбцы, изменил старые и т.д) и хочу новую структуру переместить ту что базу, что на хосте при этом не затрагия сами данные в таблицах

Comment: в любом учебнике есть раздел модификации структуры БД, этот ответ очень объемный, полагаю вам могут тут дать лишь ссылку на подробный материал. Линн Бейли - Изучаем СКЛ, раздел 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно делают систему патчей/миграций для БД. То есть на любое изменение структуры или данных пишете запросы на это изменение и запросы на откат этого изменения. А специальный скрипт накатывает (выполняет) и, если надо, откатывает изменения. Если вы работаете один, то можно просто писать запросы, помещать их в файлы названные по датам и применять код какой нужен при выкладке на боевую. Зачастую помимо изменения структуры надо еще изменить и данные в БД.
Альтернатива - скрипты, которые автоматически делают перенос структуры между базами. Тут уже разбирайтесь сами, подойдут ли они вам или нет.